# function : splitting strings, duplicating rows and replacing the original string by the splitted ones

Tags: r, string, function, loops, indexing

I'm trying for my first time to code a function. It's supposed to split a string into severals ones and returned each piece into a tibble row.

For example, let's say I have that kind of data.

```
nasty_entry <- tibble(ID = 1:3, Var = c("ABC", "AB", "A"))
```

I would like to get that.

```
nice_entry <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), var = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A"))
```

So, I try to code a function using different kind of loops (for practice) because my orignal data have about 300 entries.

```
nice_entry <- function(data, var, pattern)
  
  #--------------------DECLARATION--------------------#   
  
  # data : The tibble containing the data to split.
  # var : The variable containing the data to split.
  # pattern : The pattern to use for the spliting.
  
  if(!require(tidyverse)){install.packages("tidyverse")}
  library(tidyverse)
  if(!require(magrittr)){install.packages("tidyverse")}
  library(magrittr)
  
  c1 <- 0 # Reset the counter #1
  c2 <- 0 # Reset the counter #2
  unchanged_rows <- 0 # The number of rows that has been unchanged.
  changed_rows <- 0 # The number of rows that has been changed.
  new_data <- tibble() # The tibble where the data will be stored.
  
  repeat{
    c1 <- c1 +1 # Increase the counter #1 by one at each loop.
    c2 <- 0 # Reset the counter #2 at each loop.

    # Split the string into several strings.
    splited_str <- str_split(string = data %>% select({{ var }}) %>% slice(c1), pattern = pattern) %>% 
                   unlist()
    
    # Add the row into the "new_data" variable if the original string hasn't been splited.
    if(length(splited_str) <= 1) {
      unchanged_rows <- unchanged_rows +1
      new_data <- new_data %>% 
                  bind_rows(slice(data, c1))
      next
    }
    
    # Duplicate the row of the original string. It duplicates it several times according to the 
    # number of times the original string has been splited.
    if(length(splited_str) > 1){
      changed_rows <- changed_rows +1
      duplicated_rows <- data %>% 
                         slice(rep(c1, each = length(splited_str)))
    
      # Replace each original string with the new splited strings.
      while (c2 < length(splited_str)) {
        c2 <- c2 +1
        duplicated_rows <- duplicated_rows %>% 
                           mutate({{ var }} = replace(x = {{ var }}, list = c2, values = splited_str[c2]))
        new_data <- new_data %>% 
                    bind_rows(slice(duplicated_rows, c2))
      }
    }
    
    # Break the loop if the entire tibble has been analyse and return the "new_data" variable.
    if(c1 == length(nrow(data))) {
      break
      return(new_data)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the same code by using "real variables" inside the loops and it seems to work. The problem comes when I embrace them into the function. I get this error.

> Error: object 'c1' not found

> }
> Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

> }
> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

What do I do wrong? Maybe it's indexing problem?.

I would also like to have some advices for coding function and if there's alternatives to do the same.

Thank you very much!

Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate_rows`.  Specify a regex lookaround to match between two characters.  The `.` in regex match any character.  So, it is basically splitting between two adjacent characters

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
nasty_entry %>% 
    separate_rows(Var, sep="(?<=.)(?=.)")
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     ID Var  
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 A    
#2     1 B    
#3     1 C    
#4     2 A    
#5     2 B    
#6     3 A
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. Can you refer me on some documentations about the meaning of the signes inside the brackets "(?<=.)(?=.)". I don't know what it is.

Comment: @MathieuBernier it is a regex lookaround to match between two characters. The `.` matches for any character.  SO, it is splitting at the junction between two characters

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I needed to explore the stringr package. Thank you for you solution, it works very well! I didn't know that we could make it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach you may want to get

```
library(tidyverse)
nasty_entry2 <- nasty_entry %>% 
  mutate(Var = strsplit(as.character(Var), "")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(Var)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#      ID Var  
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     1 B    
# 3     1 C    
# 4     2 A    
# 5     2 B    
# 6     3 A
```